# Reading data from buttons of a racing wheel Genius speedwheel 3 mt

Tags: c++, c

I would like to read the data from buttons of a racing wheel Genius speedwheel 3 mt in C programming language (mainly because I want to reckognize which button was exactly pressed) but I'm not sure what format of data the wheel has. I'm guessing that the wheel sends some bytes but I don't know how many or what means each byte. Any ideas?

Comment: What OS, API or Framework ... are you using?

Comment: I'm working under Linux (specifically on Debian) and I'm writing a program in C/C++. For reading a data from the wheel I use functions open and read from fcntl.h library.